# How to select and copy table element on Microsoft Edge? (CTRL + C)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, copy, microsoft-edge

```
How to select and copy a table element on Microsoft Edge?
This works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11. Is the below code deprecated?
Please help!!

        <table id="testTable">
            <thead>
                <tr class="primary">
                    <th>Solution</th>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                    <th>C</th>
                    <th>D</th>
                    <th>E</th>
                    <th>F</th>
                    <th>G</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td>Test 1</td>
                 <td>€912 000.00</td>
                 <td>€50 640.00</td>
                 <td>€1 363 837.50</td>
                 <td>€1 322 845.33</td>
                 <td>€10 800.00</td>
                 <td>€1 041 666.67</td>
                 <td>€416 666.67</td>
                 <td>€5 118 456.17</td>
                </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>



        $("#copyAllBtn").off("click").on("click", function (event) {
            var el = document.getElementById("resulttable");
            var body = document.body, range, sel;
            if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
                range = document.createRange();
                sel = window.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                try {
                    range.selectNodeContents(el);
                    sel.addRange(range);
                } catch (e) {
                    range.selectNode(el);
                    sel.addRange(range);
                }
            } else if (body.createTextRange) {
                range = body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(el);
                range.select();
            }    
            document.execCommand("copy");                
        });
```

I know copy works on some event click, I've updated the latest code, I am calling the copy functionality on copy button click. 
The code doesn't throw any errors but doesn't do anything either on Edge. Please suggest some edits.

Comment: Where did you call `selectElementContents`? And is there any error in the console?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat I've updated the question with my latest code, I've written the copy code on a button click. There are no errors in the console, it just doesn't do anything in edge (working fine in IE11)

Answer (score 0):

I try to test your code and find that your above code example is even not working on any other browsers. It can be a logical issue. I suggest you to try to run the above example on your side to check the result.

Try to debug your code step by step can give you the information about the issue.

An alternative way is to use [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

You can try to refer an example below. It is tested with chrome and MS Edge browsers and working fine on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#copy1').click(function() {

$('tr.selected', '#exampleTable1').each(function() {

    // For each "selected" row of table1 ..
    var rowFromTable1 = $(this);

    // .. Take a clone/copy of it ..
    var clonedRowFromTable1 = rowFromTable1.clone();

    // .. And append the cloned row to the tbody of table2
    $('tbody', '#exampleTable2').append( clonedRowFromTable1 )
 })

 })

});
</script>
 
 
</head>
<body>
<table id="exampleTable1" style="max-width:50%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>bar-code</th>
            <th>product name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
            <td class="sorting_1">545333456</td>
            <td>Galaxy S9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even selected">
            <td class="sorting_1">876543</td>
            <td>Galaxy S6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">407654</td>
            <td>SD 64G </td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even selected">
            <td class="sorting_1">876543</td>
            <td>Galaxy S5</td>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">407654</td>
            <td>Iphone 7 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="exampleTable2" style="max-width:50%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>bar-code</th>
            <th>product name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-success" data-panelId="copy1" id="copy1">
    Copy from exampleTable1 To exampleTable1
</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge browser:

[image]

Further, you can modify the example as per your own requirement.

Reference:

[Copy data from selected rows of one table to another table using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376722/copy-data-from-selected-rows-of-one-table-to-another-table-using-jquery)